# maven-surefire-plugin failing with OpenJDK 17 on gitlab-ci

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, maven-surefire-plugin, openjdk-17

Running Gitlab CI suddenly started failing with this exception:

```
 /usr/java/openjdk-17/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar /builds/myapp/target/surefire/surefirebooter15709646820034007555.jar /builds/myapp/target/surefire 2021-10-12T20-04-21_120-jvmRun1 surefire10652468672509302756tmp surefire_03968859309758681259tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Unfortunately it is not really informative about what the problem really is.

However, I noticed that it was using the new openjdk-17. So I suspected it might be an issue related to this. In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` I swapped `maven:latest` with `maven:3-jdk-11` to force it to stay on JDK 11 as follows:

```
#image: maven:latest
image: maven:3-jdk-11
```

And it worked fine.

Any idea why maven-surefire-plugin failed on OpenJDK 17?

Answer (score 0):

What version of maven-surefire-plugin are you using?

Version 2.22.2 does not support Java 17 Bytecode, it does work with version 3.0.0-M9 flawlessly however. Support should be there at least since 3.0.0-M5.

Answer (score 0):

For me removing `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` in pom.xml surefire configuration :

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M9</version>
  <configuration>
    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    <argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

, leaving me with

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M9</version>
  <configuration>
    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    <argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

, fixed all my issues